# How many ways can all six numbers in the set $\{4, 3, 2, 12, 1, 6\}$ be ordered

Tags: order-theory

Is there an easy way to solve the problem?

> How many ways can all six numbers in the set $S = \{4, 3, 2, 12, 1, 6\}$ be ordered so
>   that $a$ comes before $b$ whenever $a$ is a divisor of $b$?

By analyzing each number in $S$, I get the answer, but I don't like the way I solved the problem.
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$$ $$1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 12$$ $$1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 12$$ $$1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 12$$ $$1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 12$$

Comment: This [graph of the divisor lattice for $12$](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_4r8J8-ZJgyE/S9sC091t6UI/AAAAAAAAN6g/y1BuCm1V2uI/s200/DivisorLattice.png) might help.

Comment: This type of problems are hard in general -- they reduce to (and from) counting the number of linear extensions of a given partial order, which is one of the standard examples of a [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete) problem. So don't expect a _general_ solution procedure that is significantly smarter than an exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using graph is easier. In all possibilities, 1 is always the first, and 12 is always the last. There are 5 ways to connect all the numbers from 1 to 12 as shown in the graph. You are unlikely to make a mistake or miss a line if you solve the problem this way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem by looking at the divisor lattice for $12$ and then doing casework. Here is the divisor lattice:

[image: divisor lattice for 12]

You're asking us to put any number that is below another on a tree before in the list. Therefore, $1$ is the first number since it's at the bottom. The next number is either $2$ or $3$, since those are the only nodes connected to $1$.

- After $1,2$, then we have access to $4$, but we could also go with $3$.
- - After $1,2,3$, then we have access to $6$, but we could also go with $4$. If we go with $4$, we get $1,2,3,4,6,12$ and if we go with $6$, we get $1,2,3,6,4,12$.
- - After $1,2,4$, we have to go with $3$, then $6$, then $12$, so $1,2,4,3,6,12$.
- After $1,3$, we have to go with $2$, but then we can go with either $4$ or $6$.
- - After $1,3,2,4$, we must choose $6$ then $12$, so $1,3,2,4,6,12$.
- - After $1,3,2,6$, we must choose $4$ then $12$, so $1,3,2,6,4,12$.

Thus, through this casework, we get the same $5$ solutions you did, but we went through all possible cases, so we can be sure there are no more.